# Erratum in "The Mathematics of Poker"

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy, books

I think there is a little erratum in a computation

p 79:
the result of subcase c) should be 186.36 instead of 346.21.

I didn't see that one listed in the official errata list (https://www.conjelco.com/mathofpoker/mathofpoker-errata.pdf)
Do you confirm?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because wrong site

Comment: I think is a great question and a good place for it. I'll check it out, and ask Bill myself (he's a friend).

Comment: Providing the answer as a comment since the question is closed: Yes, $186.26 should be the correct answer. The book authors likely forgot to apply the (30/45) factor to the RHS of the addition, since (15/45) (-$400) + [($2700) (29/44) - $1300] does equal $346.21.